# How to use the word “jusqu'ici” properly ?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps

Would the sentence “jusqu'ici, je le port est ouvrir” be the correct way to use it?  If not, what is the way I would say 
“Up to now, the door is open”.

Comment: Seeing the translation attempt, I'm wonderering why did you add **je**, whereas it isn't in the english sentence ?

Answer (score 4):

The correct wording would be *jusqu'ici*, note the placement of the apostrophe. The word consists of *jusque* and *ici*, where the *e* disappears and is replaced by the apostrophe.

Here is a correction of your sentence:

> Jusqu'ici, la porte a été ouverte.

or:

> Jusqu'ici, la porte était ouverte.

*The door* in French is *la porte*. The masculin word *le port* is the place where you can find ships. *La porte* is what you walk through in order to enter or exit a room.

The reason for the passé composé *a été* here is that you have a defined timespan *jusqu'ici* which defines a duration. It is very odd to use the *indicatif présent* here. You would use the present tense to describe the state of the door currently being open. Here, however, you're describing it as a state over a duration from the past up until now. Because of this past aspect, you should use a past tense, even in English:

> Up to now, the door has been open.

The adjective *open* translates to *ouvert* and here takes the female form *ouverte* because *la porte* is female. *Ouvrir* is the infinitive form of the verb *to open* in French.

Comment: I don't see any problem with *imparfait* in this sentence.

Comment: You're right. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Sander's answer, note that you can also replace *jusqu'ici* with the following expressions, which follow the same pattern:

- *Jusqu'à maintenant*
- *Jusqu'à présent*
- *Jusqu'à aujourd'hui*

These all more or less mean "Up to now" and can replace jusqu'ici in a temporal context.

Note however that *jusqu'à aujourd'hui* would not be used when talking about an event shorter than a day. If the door has been open for the last 3 hours and this is the time-frame you want to express with "Up to now", *jusqu'à aujourd'hui* would not make sense since it implies that what you're talking about has been going on for days.